# Tensor products preserve quasiiso between flat complexes

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, tensor-products, flatness

Let $f:M_\bullet \to N_\bullet$ be a quasi-isomorphism between chain complexes of flat $R$-modules for $R$ a unitary ring. Let $P$ be a right $R$-module. Is it true, and how could I prove that $$f\otimes_R P:M_\bullet \otimes_R P \to N_\bullet \otimes_R P$$ is a quasi-isomorphism?

If necessary, one may assume that $M_\bullet$ and $N_\bullet$ are bounded.

Comment: What have you tried? Notice that a map is a quasi-iso if and only if its mapping cone is acyclic. Think about the relationship between $\textsf{cone}(f\otimes_R P)$ and $ \textsf{cone}(f)\otimes_R P$.

Comment: They are isomorphic because $\_ \otimes_R P$ is additive. So it suffices to prove that $\mathsf{cone}(f)\otimes_R P$ is acyclic knowing that $\mathsf{cone}(f)$ is acylic. But I don't see why this should be simpler

Comment: Well, it reduces your problem to showing that tensoring an acyclic complex of flat modules with a module gives an acyclic complex...

Comment: @Pedro and I see that this is the problem, but I don't see how to conclude the argument. I mean, without using symmetry of Tor.